# Split data from pair of columns to multiple pairs of columns

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose that I have the following in `python` and `pandas`:

```
    Names   Values
0   A   6
1   B   8
2   C   3
3   D   5
4   E   1
5   F   3
6   D   9
7   E   6
8   F   4
9   G   3
10  D   1
11  E   5
12  F   6
```

and I want to transform this to the following:

```
    Name_1  Values_1    Name_2  Values_2    Name_3  Values_3
0   D   5   D   9   D   1
1   E   1   E   6   E   5
2   F   3   F   4   F   6
3   NA  NA  G   3   NA  NA
```

Basically what I want to do is to split the original pairs of columns in chunks of data which start with the row where `Names` is `D` and ends with the row exactly before the next `Names` is `D` starts.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: So you throw names `A, B, C` away?

Comment: Q10 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idea is create `MultiIndex` by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with compared Series with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), then reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
b = df['Names'].eq('D').cumsum()
a = df.groupby(b).cumcount()
df1 = df.set_index([a, b]).unstack().drop(0, axis=1, level=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df1.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x, y in df1.columns]
print (df1)
  Names_1  Values_1 Names_2  Values_2 Names_3  Values_3
0       D       5.0       D       9.0       D       1.0
1       E       1.0       E       6.0       E       5.0
2       F       3.0       F       4.0       F       6.0
3     NaN       NaN       G       3.0     NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) along `axis=1`:

```
grps = df.Names.eq('D').cumsum()

df_new = pd.concat([df.reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns=lambda x: f'{x}_{i}')
                    for i, df in df[grps.gt(0)].groupby(grps)], axis=1)
```

[out]

```
  Names_1  Values_1 Names_2  Values_2 Names_3  Values_3
0       D       5.0       D         9       D       1.0
1       E       1.0       E         6       E       5.0
2       F       3.0       F         4       F       6.0
3     NaN       NaN       G         3     NaN       NaN
```